Vuetify, v-data-table-virtual nested scroll bug
I'm trying to implement a virtual data table where when a row is clicked, it shows another embedded data table. However, with the row expanded, when you attempt to scroll the outer table, it gets stuck and keeps reloading the expanded row to the top...unless I'm doing something wrong...
here is the link that reproduces the bug

I can not send the link here because the link playground is over than 5k letters :( –

You should post your playground link in your question. To use links, you can use this format [display text](url)

I added the link via hyper link, please take a look to see the bug.
Also please inspect the code to see if the virtual scroll still work after fixing my bug

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Virtual table requires items to have (more or less) the same height. Otherwise, offset is not calculated correctly. When the expanded item leaves the visible area, the container shrinks as the expanded space is removed. But with the new height, the old (collapsed) item is inside the visible area, so it is drawn again in expanded state, leading to the reload effect you describe. I don't think there is a workaround for this.

yes :( I'm coding new custom not use vuetify virtual, but still wait if anyone can help :( currently the code is on prod so If I update the code will cost more effort for tester team
